# Will Design Patterns solve object communication?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, structure

I have been researching and looking for answers here to a problem that I suspect might be solved by a better understanding of design patterns. I think the problem is that I am a self-taught coder and people seem to tend to assume familiarity with a lot of esoteric terminology; I have ended up in Wikipedia spirals trying to determine what some phrases mean.
That said - on to the coding/structural problem.

Actually, just before I start, I should point out that I may well be making unknown presumptions in the way the code is structured in my question. If this is the case, could folks suggest alternatives to what I'm suggesting? I'd really appreciate learning how to better code as opposed to simply being told I'm doing it wrong.
OK...

Let's say we have a Room class, which has 4 Walls, a Ceiling and a Floor. These are instantiated 'inside' the Room. The Room also has a Table which has 4 TableLegs, again instantiated inside the Table, inside the Room. (This, I believe, is Composition, but please correct me if I've got that wrong!).

Finally, the problem:
If someone, somehow, pushes the Table, the TableLeg(s) will need to check the type of Floor they're standing on to trigger the appropriate sound. This, currently would be my solution:

The Table dispatches an event. The Room listens for that 'table pushed' event, quizes the Floor to determine its type, then passes that type to a method on Table, which in turn passes it to the TableLegs.
This, to me, seems fairly inelegant; hence my suspicion that knowledge of design patterns might be useful.
Is there something fundamentally wrong about the structure I've described that I'm not appreciating? If so, what is the alternative?

Finally, I have heard of the Gang of Four book. If that's my first port of call, is it written in an accessible style or will I have to have studied computer science to grasp it?
Sorry for the long, design-pattern-beginner's question.

Comment: You have two questions here. At least. Please ask them as separate questions. Although one of them is very likely to be closed because "Which book should I read" questions are not welcome here. However, to give you an answer to that question: the GoF is *not* a book *about* patterns. It is a book *of* patterns; it is a catalog. Trying to learn design patterns from the GoF book is like trying to learn psychology from the phone book. The GoF is a reference for looking up a particular pattern if you already know what patterns are, what that particular pattern is, and that you need it.

Comment: Sorry - I only mentioned the book because I wanted people to know I was aware of it and didn't just want people to say 'you should read this'. Thanks for your answer regarding its content though - and I can see that I probably should have avoided asking that part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Floor could listen for objects Events. The Event interface could expose information about object geometry, material, etc. Then the Floor could check for collisions and play a sound.

I recommend the book [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124)

Comment: OK, so it looks like I might need to look some more into Interfaces. I tried using them a while ago without luck and kind of gave up on them. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @RobTalsma from the HFDP book, "Strive for loosely coupled designs between objects that interact."

Comment: @RobTalsma, the Event could also be an abstract class. Just avoid coupling the objects too much. For example, does the Floor really has to know everything about an object (type), or some info would suffice? That "info" perhaps could be abstracted.
"

Comment: Hmm.. so perhaps I need to look at abstract classes some more, too. I can't pretend to know what you mean by 'that info perhaps could be abstracted'. If it's OK to ask this question - what steps would I take to provide that abstracted information?

Comment: Nick's advice is very good, but why on earth are you complicating this so much?  Get something working before you start adding all this stuff.  And be sure to use a version control system so you can tag a working release without fear of losing your working version when you refactor.

Comment: @RobTalsma, designing isn't simple. Making simple designs is even harder. It requires time, and trial and error :)

Comment: Perhaps I made myself look like TOO much of a beginner. I'm an experienced AS3 coder - but self-taught - and I'm coming to the realisation that I can't put off learning about design patterns any longer. The structure I've described is just a VERY simplified example of what I've seen happen in various projects that I've developed. If you have any specific advice on how Interfaces can facilitate communication between objects, I'd appreciate it. This page http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101-oop-introduction-to-interfaces/ was a good, but didn't address that issue. Thanks.

Comment: @RobTalsma, a pattern you could use is the Observer pattern. Interfaces is an implementation detail. Interfaces can help to keep the code simple, but patterns might do the opposite. Anyway, if many types share a common behavior, you can expose it through an interface. For example, a TableLeg object can be exposed as a RigidBody. The Floor could listen for rigid body events, inspect RigidBody properties and do something. The Floor doesn't need to know about specific types, like Table, TableLeg, Chair, etc.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I'd like to know, then, what the Floor would be attaching its listener TO? ie:

Comment: So, in Floor, <what object goes here?>.addEventListener(EventType.CONSTANT_NAME, handlerFunction)

Comment: @RobTalsma, Rigid bodies could have Listeners attached to them, or perhaps simpler, keep a global/world/room event queue (or direct calls). Every object could then send/add an event there. You can subscribe the Floor to the Room for Rigid body events.

Comment: I'm keen to figure this out (and don't have enough rep to move this to chat) but I can't follow exactly what you mean. I've heard avoiding Global objects is a good thing. And if the RigidBodies are on a different 'branch' of the composition, how would they hear events from Floor? Clearly, I am confused...

Comment: @RobTalsma, Global isn't always bad. Here "global" can be the Room and all objects can belong to a Room. If you want you can have a global event system, if it adds value to your program. Don't be afraid to use global/helper data structures.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I can answer your question, but I can tell you something about the "Design Patterns" book.

It was an instant classic when it was published in 1994/1995.  With examples in C++ and Smalltalk (there was no Java or C# back then), it listed solutions to 26 common problems in object-oriented programming.  It provided a format for documenting forces and resolutions that was eagerly snapped up by academic conferences for years after.  Lots of programmers, including myself, were studying it like holy writ in the hope that a single book could make them superstars.

Then reality set in.

Functional programmers said the patterns were work-arounds for flaws in OOP.  What's the fuss?  They could do these things without resorting to patterns.

The usual response on first reading the book is to try and fit as many patterns as you can into whatever code you happen to be writing at that moment.

You'll find yourself using the pattern names in design sessions: "I think we need a Chain of Responsibility here!"

Eventually you calm down and realize that patterns aren't the answers to your problems.  The best way to use them is to think hard about your problems and solutions and suddenly realize that your answer happens to fall into a pattern.

As for your problem, I don't think you need a pattern.  Have the Table send a message to the Floor to ask about its type before you generate the sound.  That'll do it.  Simplicity is a virtue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get the feeling the structure I'm suggesting leads to some very convoluted code, is all. I don't seem to have an instinct for what should happen when an instance seems to need information from 'outside' itself and suspect there's something fundamental that I haven't picked up. I don't want to annoy anyone here - do I need to ask this a different question now?

Comment: My advice?  Do something simple that works, then build on that.  Keep going until you run into a problem, then fix that.

Comment: @RobTalsma, yes first try something simple. When you have concrete, duplicated, code then see if you can/should abstract.

Comment: I see nothing abstract in your problem statement.  Room?  Table?  What if I add a Table with 3 legs?  What if I drag in a Chest instead of a Table?  Does it make a sound?  No Chair?  What about Ottoman?  You're falling into a deep, deep hole.

Comment: If the Table had 3 TableLegs, it would only instantiate 3. I'm not sure I understand what kind of hole I'm falling into. I think, perhaps, you're alluding to abstraction, but I'm not sure what that means. I am new to these concepts, so baby steps would be appreciated. If you can't (or don't want to) explain it clearly, can you suggest somewhere that can? I will, likewise, continue my research. Thanks.

Comment: @duffymo RE: 'keep going until you run into a problem'. Just to be clear, this is why I've posted the orginal question. I have REPEATEDLY run into this problem of having deeply nested, seemingly redundant, function calls and I'm trying to find out if there's a more elegant solution that I should be employing. Once again, if you have the patience to explain what you mean by your questions in your second comment, I'd appreciate it. Thanks again.

Comment: I think I'm explaining it quite clearly: abstraction is a two edged sword.  It can help when you understand your problem and how it can change very well, but it can be more difficult to grok.  You add abstraction when you've implemented one or two concrete attempts and understand where abstraction helps.  You say you're new to these concepts.  I say it's wrong to jump to the end from where you are.

Comment: Asking a bunch of questions is not explaining it particularly clearly. I understand that once one comprehends something it can be hard to recall the steps required to achieve that comprehension. I would like you to explain, practically, how abstraction would be used to solve this problem, please. I am keen to learn.